# Change of radix without using radix 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If one has a number in radix $b$: $(d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_0)_b$, and wants to change to radix $p$, how could one achieve that without passing from $b$ to $10$ and then from $10$ to $p$?

I thought I had solved it using the nested form of the number,i.e. $d_0 +b(d_{1}+b(d_{2}+b(\ldots)))$, and then changing radix from the inside, but I realised that this form of the number is in base $10$. Actually the definition is in base $10$:
$$d_nb^n+\ldots+d_1b+d_0,$$

So I'm really having trouble with comming up with a solution to the problem of changing radix without using base $10$. Can you give me any hints? Thanks!

Comment: So, represent all your $d$'s and $b$ in radix $p$, and do all your arithmetic in base $p$.

Comment: one main problem is that we think of $b^k$ in base 10, for example convert to binary, the columns are given by 1,2,4,8,16,32,... which is base 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about base ten, except our cultural familiarity with the digits $0 \dots 9$. The process for converting from base $a$ to base $b$ is the same as that of converting from base $a$ to base ten or base ten to base $b$.

Given a number $N_a$ in base $a$, one way to obtain $N_b$ in base $b$ is to repeatedly perform long division in base $a$.

First calculate $N_a \div b_a$, obtaining an integer part $\lfloor N \div b\rfloor_a$ and a remainder $(N \bmod b)$. The remainder is the one's place of the result in base $b$. Take the quotient and repeat the process of long division to obtain the next digit. Repeat until the dividend is zero.

That's the naive way, but it's a bit of work. Each long division requires one step per digit of $N_a$, and we need one division per digit of $N_b$. Each long division step involves several digits, specifically the length of the representation $b_a$. Since the number of digits is represented by the $\log_n$ function, the total work is $O\left( \log_a b \cdot \log_a N \cdot \log_b N \right) = O\left( \frac{\ln^2 N \cdot \ln b}{\ln^2 a \cdot \ln b} \right) = O\left( {\log_a}^2 N \right)$. In other words, it goes up quadratically with the length (in digits) of the original number, but it does not depend on $b$.

Other algorithms exist, but I'm not sure if any are better. If you can increase $b$ without difficulty, then you can convert first from base $a$ to base $c = b^n$, and then to base $b$, taking advantage of the fact that each digit in $c$ corresponds to a sequence of $n$ digits in base $b$. For example, computer programmers familiar with hexadecimal (base 16) will often deal with that instead of binary, since it's easier for the human brain. This doesn't represent a genuine reduction in complexity, though;  it's really just shifted into the subtraction operations.

Answer (score 3):

**Numbers** do not have a base; a given **radix representation** of a number does. For example, there is a certain number of dots below.
$$\LARGE\bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet\\
\LARGE\bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet\\
\LARGE\bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet\quad \bullet$$
To adapt a section from *Lockhart's Lament*:

> Twelve does not "start with a one" or "end with a two". Twelve itself doesn't start or end, it just *is*. (What does a pile of dots "start" with?) It is only the Hindu-Arabic decimal place-value *representation* of twelve that starts with a `1` and ends with a `2`.

So you're incorrect when you say that
$$d_nb^n+\ldots+d_1b+d_0$$
is *"in base $10$"*, this is simply **the number** that the representation $(d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_0)_b$ corresponds to. You many then proceed to divide this number by $p$, take the remainder and quotient, divide that quotient by $p$, etc. to get the representation of the number in base $p$, and all of this is done without any mention of $10$.

Comment: So if I want to convert $132_8$ to base $7$, I divide $132_8/7=14_8$ remainder $6$, $14_8/7=1$ remainder $5$, so $132_8=156_7$.  If you can do arithmetic in the bases you are fine.  If not, go through base $10$.

Comment: @Ross: Indeed, but when it comes to doing an actual computation the bases $b$ and $p$ are presumably given in a human-comfortable base (such as base $10$) so that when we are computing the number
$$d_nb^n+\ldots+d_1b+d_0$$
we are doing so in a human-comfortable base (such as base $10$). My answer was more focused on describing abstractly what is necessary to convert from base $b$ to base $p$.

Comment: I didn't say it was the easy way.  I did the computations in base $8$.I was just trying to give a concrete example to show one can convert between bases without going through base $10$ to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, there is not much to be gained by not going through base $10$. We can use $mod$ to determine the necessary values, but this is effectively using base $10$ by proxy.

If the two bases are related, i.e. $b_1|b_2$ we can make some progress, but we hit the same problem as before with the $b_2/b_1$ being not nice.

If $b_1^k=b_2$ we can make rapid progress however. Each $b_2^x$ represents a sum of $b_1^y$'s, and so we can directly convert from one to the other. For example consider base $8$ to base $2$:

> $6723_8 \to (110)(111)(010)(011)_2 \to 110111010011_2$
>
> $1011011_2 \to (001)(011)(011)_2 \to 133_8$

If $b_1^j=b_2^k$ we can also make progress.

An example is to convert from base $8$ to base $4$. This line shows the first step, but is not the answer.

> $574035_8 \to (22)(13)(20)(00)(12)(11)_4$

From the right-hand side, the method for determining the pairs alternates between the normal conversion of a digit $d_8\to d_4$ and converts double the digit, for example $5_8=11_4 \to 22$ in pair formation, and $7_8=13_4\to (26)\to 32$.

To convert we need to add pairs together starting from the right-hand side. This is because the **1** column in base $8$ spills into the **4** and **1** columns in base $4$. And the **8** column in base $8$ spills into the **16** and **4** columns in base $4$. And the **64** column in base $8$ spills into the **256** and **64** columns in base $4$. And so on. So $(12)(11)\to (131)$. That is every pair produces $3$ digits towards the answer, relative to the bases being $2^3$ and $2^2$. There are no carries because the sum parts consists of either $0$ or $2$ from the left pair, and $0$ or $1$ from the right pair.

> $(22)(13)(20)(00)(12)(11)_4 \to (233)(200)(131)_4 \to 233200131_4$

To convert from base $4$ into base $8$ we reverse the process, which we can do because the middle digits from each triple is uniquely defined.

> $32012_4 \to (032)(012) \to (02)(12)(00)(12) \to (01)(12)(00)(12) \to 1606_8$

halving alternate pairs.

Comment: "We can use mod to determine the necessary values, but this is effectively using base 10 by proxy." … unless you don't use base 10.

Comment: @Potato, I'm seeing how people can get confused; they think that the arithmetic with all the carrying and borrowing has to be done in decimal base when the same concepts exactly carry over to other bases.

Comment: @Potatoswatter; if you think more naturally in base 103...everything we do is in base 10 - i can't see how to avoid this (i bet you thought i meant base 28, i mean base 26)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Not everything we do is in base 10. The rules of place-value arithmetic are the same no matter the base. A good answer to this question should mention why place-value arithmetic is a good choice in the first place (efficient representation of numbers as a sequence of symbols from a finite set) and then present an algorithm for converting one place-value representation to another.

Comment: @Potatoswatter; what do you mean by base 10? 1000? 995353? (btw this is my answer so you don't need to @ me)

Comment: It's nice to use @ to remove the ambiguity — I'm not replying to Guess. "Base 10" is the place-value number system using the digits 0 up to 9 (or any ten symbols). It's fun to remark that any base is "base 10" in its own similar place-value notation, but that adds nothing but confusion to the conversation or exposition. In practice, subscripts should be used when the base needs to be specified.

Comment: @Potatoswatter; 'subscripts should be used when the base needs to be specified' - other than the **default base 10**?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No. The base needs to be specified when it's ambiguous from the context of the presentation. It's important to combat ambiguity, as it's a source of confusion. There are situations where the base is obviously 2, 36, 64, or otherwise, and no subscript is needed. In this Q&A, writing a subscript 10 is probably a good idea.

Comment: so I should write $10_{10_{10_{10_{\dots}}}}$ to be sure

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I get the sense that you're not seriously trying to help the asker. You should communicate in the most effective manner you can.